# How to configure Brackets as git core.editor in Windows

Tags: git, adobe-brackets

I'm trying to configure Git to use Adobe's Brackets as the core editor on my Windows 7 laptop. I'm using Git Bash. I have it working on a Mac at school, so I know it's possible (although after saving a file that Git opens in brackets for me to edit, I have to completely exit Brackets for it to register to Git; simply closing the file doesn't work). 
This is what I have configured on the Mac that works:

> `git config --global core.editor "open -nW -a 'Brackets’"`

This is what I've tried so far on Windows:

> `git config --global core.editor "'c:/program files (x86)/brackets/brackets.exe' open -n -w"`

with combinations of "open -n -nW -wl1 -a" as options

If I don't have Brackets already open, then this works fine- it opens Brackets and opens the file for me to edit (although again, I have to completely exit Brackets for it to register to Git as saved).

However, if I already have Brackets open, all it does it tab over to Brackets- it doesn't open up the file and it's contents at all. It doesn't matter if I have a working file open or none at all- all Git does is activate Brackets but doesn't open the file.

If anyone has any ideas how to fix this, please let me know.. it would also be nice if I could get Git to acknowledge my save by closing the edited file after saving instead of having to exit the entire program, but more than anything I just need it to open the files correctly on Windows Brackets. Thanks!

Comment: did you manage to sort out this?

Comment: I did.. It was a long time ago but if I recall correctly, it needed back slashes to work. May be mistaken though.

Answer (score 2):

In windows 8 powershell its Same as Mac or Linux

```
git config --global core.editor brackets
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on GitBash:

```
$ echo 'alias brackets="c:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Brackets/Brackets.exe"
```

(You need backslash \ to escape spaces and parenthesis.)

GitBash displays no confirmation or error message for me.  Close GitBash. Open GitBash.  Type the following:

```
$ brackets
```

and it should open Brackets.

I found the solution on Udacity on how to set up GitBash to open the Sublime editor. https://www.udacity.com/wiki/ud775/sublime

Answer (score 0):

It will be simple
In linux.

```
git config --global core.editor brackets
```

In windows test it

```
git config --global core.editor 'c:/program files (x86)/brackets/brackets.exe'
```

Answer (score -2):

```
git config --global core.editor "C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\Brackets.exe"
```

Windows path statements use backslashes... and quotes needed for spaces.