# git aborting commit immediately - Brackets editor

Tags: git, git-commit, adobe-brackets

I have set my core editor for git commit messages to Brackets.io but unfortunately it's always showing up this message

```
Aborting commit; you did not edit the message.
```

I try doing `-w` & `-W` to make it wait until I write my commit but with no luck!

Any help?

Comment: What command are you using to launch brackets?

Comment: Looking here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23002594/how-to-configure-brackets-as-git-core-editor-in-windows , it seems that getting bracket to work for commit messages may be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @adelphus .. git commit

Answer (score 1):

Try one of the [configurations of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23002594/6309), that is: without any `open -nW` option, and see if that is enough to avoid that error message.

---

Note that the error message you saw in 2015 will change with Git 2.14.x/2.15 (Q3 2017)
You now should see:

```
Aborting commit due to empty commit message
```

See [commit bc17f35](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bc17f35f8c65295fbfcb281dda8560136fb26fb4) (17 Jul 2017) by [Kaartic Sivaraam (`sivaraam`)](https://github.com/sivaraam).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 2b473ce](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2b473ce78c5af196caf219fe021c0453108e0244), 11 Aug 2017)</sup>

> ### `commit`: check for empty message before the check for untouched template
>
> The check for whether the template given to '`git commit`' is untouched
>   is done before the empty message check.
>   This results in a wrong error message being displayed in the following case:
>
> > When the user removes everything in template completely to abort the commit he is shown the "template untouched" error which is wrong.
> >     He should be shown the "empty message" error.
>
> Do the empty message check before checking for an untouched template
>   thus fixing this issue.

Comment: I don't think change of error message will help OP in any way. However, [link you gave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23002594/how-to-configure-brackets-as-git-core-editor-in-windows) just might.

Comment: @eis I agree: the first part of the answer is for documenting a change in Git behavior, which will allow future readers having the same issue to find this question.

Comment: it might be feasible to flip the answer around, moving second part at the top and first part as an additional comment? it's easy to miss the actual fix suggestion